# Python declarative loop refactor (need access multiple elements)

Tags: python, declarative-programming

Hi I have this piece of code and trying to refactor it to be declarative. But AFAIK, all declarative methods like `map()` `reduce()` `filter()` will loop through each element of the container, not a few like this

```
def arrayCheck(nums):

    # Note: iterate with length-2, so can use i+1 and i+2 in the loop
    for i in range(len(nums)-2):
        # Check in sets of 3 if we have 1,2,3 in a row
        if nums[i]==1 and nums[i+1]==2 and nums[i+2]==3:
            return True
    return False
```

So how to write this code, declarative way?

Comment: `any(nums[i]==1 and nums[i+i] ==3 and nums[i+2] == 3 for i in range(len(nums)-2))` which essentially is equivalent to your loop (and is implemented as such under the hood). Of course, you could always use recursion

Comment: It should be noted, Python is an eminently imperative language... although it supports various declarative/functional constructs, often, it is better to stick to the imperative constructs rather than do, say, a recursive approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can use a `zip` to rewrite your loop:

```
def array_check(nums):
    for a, b, c in zip(nums, nums[1:], nums[2:]):
        if a == 1 and b == 2 and c == 3:
            return True
    return False
```

Then, use the tuple comparison:

```
def array_check(nums):
    for a, b, c in zip(nums, nums[1:], nums[2:]):
        if (a, b, c) == (1, 2, 3):
            return True
    return False
```

And then the `any` builtin:

```
def array_check(nums):
    return any((a, b, c) == (1, 2, 3) for a, b, c in zip(nums, nums[1:], nums[2:]))
```

Test:

```
>>> array_check([1,3,4,1,2,3,5])
True
>>> array_check([1,3,4,1,3,5])
False
```

Note: for a faster version, see @juanpa.arrivillaga comment below.

---

If you want to mimic functional style:

```
import operator, functools

def array_check(nums):
    return any(map(functools.partial(operator.eq, (1,2,3)), zip(nums, nums[1:], nums[2:])))
```

But that's *really* unpythonic!

Comment: You can just do `return any(trip == (1, 2, 3) for trip in zip(nums, nums[1:], nums[2:]))`, i.e. no need to unpack if you are just going to pack it up again, just wastes bytecode instructions. Note, the top version is still imperative

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga The top version is a step towards the bottom version. You are right about bytecode instructions, but performance is not my goal here.

Comment: Sure, I was mostly being tounge-in-cheek, but I do think all the unpacking/packing hurts readability. A matter of taste I suppose. The performance issue is trivial, if I were going to improve the performance I'd start by removing the slicing to get constant space...